# Stream multiple API responses in Next14

Tags: node.js, next.js, stream, next.js13

I am trying to make multiple API calls that do not depend on each other. For the sake of understanding this, lets say that these API calls cannot fail.

The reason I want to do this is that I do not want to wait for the results of 10 API calls and I want to receive them as they are resolved. Order also does not matter.

In my actual code (with the real API calls) I have noticed that the `controller` is closed after some API calls when it should only be closed once all API calls are resolved.

#### API code

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

export async function GET() {
    const stream = new ReadableStream({
        async start(controller) {
            const encoder = new TextEncoder();
            let promises = [];
            for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                promises.push(test(i, encoder, controller));
            }
            await Promise.allSettled(promises);

            controller.close();
        },
    });
    return new NextResponse(stream);
}

async function test(i: number, encoder: TextEncoder, controller: ReadableStreamDefaultController) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    const result = { result: i };
    const queue = encoder.encode(JSON.stringify(result));
    controller.enqueue(queue);
}
```

#### Front-end code

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/stream-test`, {
        method: "GET",
      });
      const reader = response.body?.getReader();
      const decoder = new TextDecoder();
      while (true && reader != null) {
        const { value, done } = await reader.read();
        if (done) break;
        const decoded = JSON.parse(decoder.decode(value));
        setStreamRes((prev) => [...prev, decoded]);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    }
  };
```